# How to prevent infinite loop with two widgets that update each other?

Tags: python, jupyter, infinite-loop, onchange, ipywidgets

I'm experimenting with [Jupyter Widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io) to see if I can make a better version of [this](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/interactive-design-tools/dbconvert.html#), but apparently the observe handler triggers even when the change is not from the user, so it creates an infinite loop of one widget changing the other. Minimal example:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

a = widgets.FloatText(description='a:')
b = widgets.FloatText(description='b:')


def on_a_change(change):
    b.value = change['new'] + 1
    
a.observe(on_a_change, names='value')


def on_b_change(change):
    a.value = change['new'] + 1

b.observe(on_b_change, names='value')


display(a)
display(b)
```

Is there any way to only trigger on a user-initiated change?  In other words, the user updates one text box, and then the others are updated from it, but those updates don't trigger more updates.

Comment: Maybe something like https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Debouncing can be adapted to limit the number of updates so they each update each other once and then stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the requirement, but if it is "update one more than other", then you can try the following

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

a = widgets.FloatText(description='a:')
b = widgets.FloatText(description='b:')

def update_one(x):
    return x + 1

widgets.link((a, 'value'), (b, 'value'), (update_one, update_one))

display(a)
display(b)
```

`widgets.link` seems to do the trick, if you do `widgets.link.__doc__` you can see the docs and it accepts a third parameter.

```
>>> print(widgets.link.__doc__)
Link traits from different objects together so they remain in sync.

    Parameters
    ----------
    source : (object / attribute name) pair
    target : (object / attribute name) pair
    transform: iterable with two callables (optional)
        Data transformation between source and target and target and source.
```

So I have added an iterable of callables and made it return `1` more than your entered value.

Comment: No the "+ 1" is just an example of how it creates an infinite loop of `a` changing `b`, which then changes `a`, which then changes `b`.  When the user updates `a`, it should update `b` (and `c` and `d`), and then stop.  When the user updates `b`, it should update `a` (and `c` and `d`), and then stop.  `link` might actually work, though?  I will experiment with it

Comment: `link` looks like it will work!  I thought it was just for making things track each other, but the ability to transform makes it perfect for what I'm doing

Comment: working (though much slower to load than javascript of course): https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/endolith/unit_converter/HEAD?urlpath=%2Fvoila%2Frender%2Funit%20converter.ipynb

Comment: that looks cool, and thanks for introducing me to binder :D

Comment: That's the Voilà rendering, the normal Binder notebook is here: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/endolith/unit_converter/HEAD

Comment: I was wondering how you managed to link multiple widgets, that's some nice dictionary action going on, I was planning on asking but you linked the source :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also `unobserve` a function when you change the value, and then reset it later.

```py
def on_a_change(change):
    b.unobserve(on_b_change, names='value')
    b.value = change['new'] + 1
    b.observe(on_b_change, names='value')
```